# Ethereum programming language

Tags: python

I want to learn ethereum from the ground up. Is ethereum written in python or golang or another langauge?

With written I mean the reference implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both - because ethereum is a network of co-operating nodes, it's really good for the robustness of the ecosystem to have multiple implementations.

The client written in golang (often called `geth`) has a focus on efficiency, and is [`ethereum/go-ethereum`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) on GitHub.

The client written in python has a particular focus on readability, and is [`ethereum/pyethapp`](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp) on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you very much! So learning Python first is a good choice if I wanto to learn Ethereum from the ground up?

Comment: What is ethereum/pyethereum?

Comment: @Invader it's the python library which handles core ethereum task. The command-line client pyethapp uses it to do stuff

Comment: It's probably more useful to learn python than go if the goal is understanding ethereum. But the formal specification is also available at yellowpaper.io - although it's really formal and math-heavy.

Comment: Is it necessary to understand all the stuff in the formal specification before digging into ethereum code or is it enough to understand the whitepaper?

Comment: @Invader I dunno! I'm pretty new to this stuff honestly, and I haven't gone through any of the implementation code, or even deployed a contract of my own. Good luck!